# Paperclip configuration to use with openshift

Tags: ruby, image, paperclip, openshift

I'm trying to configure paperclip to use it with openshift but I can't do it right, any suggestion?

```
has_attached_file :photo,
                :styles => {
                :thumb=> "100x100#",
                :small  => "400x400>"
            },
             :url  => "/assets/users_folder/:id/:style/:id.:extension",
             :path => ENV['OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR']+"public/assets/users_folder/:id/:style/:id.:extension"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended doing this:

```
:url  => "/assets/:id.:extension",<br>
:path => ":rails_root/public/assets/:id.:extension"
```

and on the deploy file of openshif ( /.openshift/action_hooks/deploy ):

```
STORED_ASSETS="${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/assets"
LIVE_ASSETS="${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/public/assets"

\# Ensure our stored assets directory exists
if [ ! -d "${STORED_ASSETS}" ]; then
  echo "  Creating permanent assets directory"
  mkdir "${STORED_ASSETS}"
fi

\# Create symlink to stored assets unless we're uploading our own assets
if [ -d "${LIVE_ASSETS}" ]; then
  echo "  WARNING: Assets included in git repository, not using stored assets"
else
  echo "  Restoring stored assets"
  ln -sf "${STORED_ASSETS}" "${LIVE_ASSETS}"
fi
```

that way we created a link to our data folder (OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR) that will never be removed by git pushes.

Comment: I have tried your way and still it gets deleted. could you please explain wht this does

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by alfredo in your models in order to save different styles for different models to - similar to Paperclip's default:

```
has_attached_file :image,
                :url => "/uploads/:class/:attachment/:id/:style_:filename",
                :path => ":rails_root/public/uploads/:class/:attachment/:id/:style_:filename"
```

Quick explanations:

- :rails_root will be your rails root
- :class will be the name of your model of the image (pluralized)
- :attachment will be the name of the field (pluralized)
- :id will be the current id of the model
- :style_ will be the styles you have defined for your images (eg thumb, original, etc)
- :filename will be the final filename in the folder
  (rails_root is your rails root, class is usually the name of your model, attachment is the name of the field, id is the id of the model, style is the style you have defined - thumb etc - and filename is the filename for the image)

Notice the change of the /assets/ to /uploads/ folder. Based on your git configuration the assets folder might be deleted.

Finally, at the end of the /.openshift/action_hooks/deploy file:

```
STORED_ASSETS="${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}/uploads"    LIVE_ASSETS="${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/public/uploads"

# Ensure our stored assets directory exists
if [ ! -d "${STORED_ASSETS}" ]; then
echo " Creating permanent assets directory"
mkdir "${STORED_ASSETS}"
fi

# Create symlink to stored assets unless we're uploading our own assets
if [ -d "${LIVE_ASSETS}" ]; then
echo " WARNING: Assets included in git repository, not using stored     assets"
else
echo " Restoring stored assets"
ln -sf "${STORED_ASSETS}" "${LIVE_ASSETS}"
fi
```